# Ruby on rails Mysql on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to develop ruby on rails aplication using mysql database in Ubuntu environment.
I have installed rails and mysql succesfully. But when I try to generate model, it reports the message

```
 rails g model person
      invoke  active_record
/home/meuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

Then I tried to install activerecord-mysql-adapter:

```
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$ gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter, activerecord-fb-adapter, activerecord-odbc-adapter, activerecord-jdbc-adapter
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$
```

Initiated by the answers below, I also tried this:

```
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$ gem "mysql2", "< 0.3"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command mysql2,
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$
```

And this:

```
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$ gem 'mysql2'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command mysql2
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$
```

And this:

```
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$  gem install "mysql2" -v=2.8.17
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2' (= 2.8.17) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: mysql2
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$
```

And this:

```
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$ sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
[sudo] password for meuser: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.
libmysql-ruby is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$ gem "mysql2", "< 0.3"
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command mysql2,
meuser@ubuntu:~/myproject$
```

Here is my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  database: myproject_db
  username: root
  password: somepassword
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Does anyone knows solution for this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: You have the answer in the error message: "Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter gem is called 'mysql2', and you need add it to your gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Then run the `bundle` command and edit your database.yml file to point to the right database:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: yourapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: @SonOfOmer I see your updates, you need to put that code in your gemfile.

Comment: Is it command to run or I need to update some file, the gemfile. I am really not sure what are you telling me. Thanks.

Comment: In your rails application there is a file called `Gemfile`. Edit it and add `gem 'mysql2'`. The run the `bundle` command.

Answer (score -1):

try to install mysql2 gem in version  < 0.3 like 0.2.8 it is common issue.

in Gemfile type

```
gem "mysql2", "< 0.3"
```

Comment: When installing this gem you may need also have libmysql-dev to build ruby extension

Comment: eg. gem install "mysql2" -v=2.8.17